# Android Adobe PNG Settings for Action Bar Icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I created some icons in illustrator and I am trying to make icons for some buttons, but they are coming out fuzzy, not crisp. I really can't find a good tutorial online.

Look at my sample

[image: Screen Shot]

These are the steps I take after the icon is complete

```
1. Create a new image with 32x32
2. Copy and Paste the icon and resize it according to <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html">Android Specs</a>

3. File->Save For Web
4. See screenshot for settings
```

[image: Adobe Illustrator Settings Screenshot]

Can someone either let me know if I am using the wrong settings or just my technique? Can someone share how they make icons and make them look good?

Comment: RU setting icon image to your Button background ?

Comment: probably not.. what do I need to do?